# How to get HttpStatusCode from Exception in WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-web-api

Is there anyway we can get HttpStatus code when exception caught? Exceptions could be `Bad Request`, `408 Request Timeout`,`419 Authentication Timeout`? How to handle this in exception block?

```
 catch (Exception exception)
            {
                techDisciplines = new TechDisciplines { Status = "Error", Error = exception.Message };
                return this.Request.CreateResponse<TechDisciplines>(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, techDisciplines);
            }
```

Comment: -1 This is clearly code to produce HttpResponses. Not to handle them.

Answer (score 2):

I notice that you're catching a generic Exception. You'd need to catch a more specific exception to get at its unique properties. In this case, try catching `HttpException` and examining its status code property.

However, if you are authoring a service, you may want to use `Request.CreateResponse` instead to report error conditions.
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling has more information

Answer (score 2):

I fell into the same trap when doing error handling in my WebAPI controllers. I did some research on best practices for exception handling and finally ended up with following stuff that works like a charm (hope it will will help :)

```
try
{       
    // if (something bad happens in my code)
    throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) { Content = new StringContent("custom error message here") });
}
catch (HttpResponseException)
{
    // just rethrows exception to API caller
    throw;
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    // casts and formats general exceptions HttpResponseException so that it behaves like true Http error response with general status code 500 InternalServerError
    throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) { Content = new StringContent(x.Message) });
}
```